# find_first_not_of in php?

Tags: php, string

In c++ there is function : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/

> Searches the string for the first character that does not match any of the characters specified in its arguments.

```
std::size_t found = str.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ");
```

Is there something like this in php ?

Comment: And what research have you done?

Comment: I don't think this function exists.  Though you can probably make it with some calls to other functions.

Comment: I only found: http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php - but it is only for positive search (Returns a string starting from the character found, or FALSE if it is not found.)

Comment: There is something pretty similar... look it up: http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Answer (score 3):

Based on my extremely quick review of that C++ description, [strcpn](https://www.php.net/strcspn) sounds close.

Comment: @Fleshgrinder: [Neither is `find_first_not_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), so I presume the OP wants something non-mb-safe.

Comment: So the OP is basically searching for the first number (hence the string `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "`)? I guess there would be faster approaches for that than using `strcspn()`.

Comment: @Fleshgrinder: Or punctuation.  Or control character/non-printable.  Regardless, `strcspn` is a wrapper around the C function of the same name and I presume is optimized for fast string searches.  I would be surprised if there is a faster method in PHP.

Comment: We don't know, but it's definitely the right answer to the question if multi-byte is from no concern and if it is https://github.com/Impreshin/Impreshin/blob/master/lib/finediff.php#L702

Answer (score 1):

This is something I would generally use regular expressions for.

```
// Return index of first non-matching character, or -1 on not found.
function find_first_not_of($str, $chars)
{
  // todo: escape $chars, or not, depending on the desired behavior

  return preg_match('/^[' . $chars . ']*(.)/', $str, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) ? $m[1][1] : -1;
}

echo find_first_not_of('Hello, World!', 'A-Za-z');
```